# Convex Optimization of quadratic function with inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

How would I solve the following problem?

$$\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} x^T A x$$ subject to the constraints $$x_i\geq 1,\,i=1,\dots,n,$$

where A is positive semidefinite and symmetric. Is it possible to solve that analytically? In what cases is the solution simply given by $x_1,\dots,x_n=1$?

Thank you!

Comment: $x^* = \mathbf{1}$ is an optimal solution if $\mathbf{1}$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Why is that? Unfortunately I don't understand that yet. Could you give some more details or do you know a reference?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem

Since $||x||_2 \geq 1$, we have that $\lambda_n \leq R_A(x) \leq x^TAx$.  This is only a sufficient condition; however it might also be the answer for a different reason.

Comment: I think that might be a good tip, thank you (I still don't get it completely, but I have good hopes that I will once I've had a closer look at the Rayleigh quotient).

Comment: Hmm, doesn't help, unfortunately that eigenvector isn't **1**. But thanks anayway.

Comment: What do you mean by "analytical"? You do have an analytical solution in this case from the KKT conditions, but it's impractical to compute because you will need to check $2^n$ options for the different configurations of your Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite the problem as follows.

$$\min x^TAx $$
$$ \text{s.t.} 1 - x \le 0 $$

This is a convex optimization problem in standard form, where $1$ is a vector of ones.  We write the lagrage function.

$$ L(x,\lambda) = x^TAx + <\lambda, 1 - x> $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow $$
$$ L(x,\lambda) = x^TAx + \lambda - <\lambda, x> $$

Differentiating

$$ \nabla L _X(x,\lambda) = Ax - \lambda $$

We know solution must be where the gradient of the lagragian is zero.  so

$$ Ax = \lambda $$

$$ x^* = A^{-1}\lambda $$

And and A is invertible.

Complimentary condition.

$$ \lambda_i( 1 - x_i) = 0 $$

If $x_i = 1$ then we already have the solution for the $i$ if not then $\lambda _i $ would have to be zero. but then the optimiality conidition from before would not hold.  So $x_i^* = 1 \forall i$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that not ALL of the $\lambda_i$ can be zero because then $x*=A^{-1}\lambda=0$. But couldn't SOME of the $\lambda_i$ be zero (and thus SOME of the $x_i$ be something else than 1)?

Comment: I wrote down the problem for the case $n=2$ and tried to solve it using Kuhn-Tucker conditions as you suggested. So suppose $$A=\left(\begin{eqnarray} a & b\\b & d\end{eqnarray}\right).$$ Then I obtain the following three possibilities: $$1.)\quad x_1=x_2=1.$$ $$2.)\quad x_1=1, x_2=-b/d \text{ (if } \lambda_2=0).$$  $$3.)\quad x_1=-b/a\text{ (if }\lambda_1=0).$$ Is this right?

Comment: Forgot to add that $x_2=1$ in the latter case. By feasibility (because $x_1\geq 1$), 2.) and 3.) can only happen if $sign(b)\neq sign(d)$ or $sign(b)\neq sign(a)$ respectively. Further, it has to hold that $b\geq d$ or $b\geq a$ respectively.

Comment: (Take abstract values in the last part of the previous comment). What I don't understand now is, considering that the problem is convex, how comes I have three possibilities? I mean, there can be only one optimum in a convex problem, right?

Comment: I think there are some side cases.  A zero matrix would be positive semi definite but all solutions are optimal because all values of the function are zero.  If you have strict convexity it holds.  Because A is the hessian we have to use its semi positive definiteness in some way.

Comment: What holds if I have strict convexity (you wrote "it" holds, but I'm not sure what you mean)? My question is actually more a research question so it would already help if I could say something about strictly positive definite matrices (excluding the zeros case you mentioned). So let's just assume A is strictly positive definite and symmetric then. Does that help?

Comment: $\lambda$ is a vector, but it's being added with a scalar, so I think there's an error.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run a good QP solver on that problem (MOSEK, GUROBI,CPLEX....). If you want, you can transform in conic form:

$$ \min t$$
$$ s.t.  $$
$$ t\geq ||y||_2 $$
$$ y= Fx $$
$$ x_i\geq 1\quad i=1,\ldots,n$$

where $F$ is a Cholesky factorization of $A$. Then you can restate the first constraint as $(t,f)\in Q$, i.e. they must belong to a second-order cone.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for an analytical solution.